# dplyr evaluation: select() vs. mutate()

Tags: r, select, dplyr, nse

Can anyone explain why the dplyr approach that works with `select()` does not work with `mutate()`?

Minimal Working Example:

```
data <- as.tibble(cbind(c(1,2,3,4),c(5,6,7,8)))
func <- function(data, var){
  data %>% select(!!var)
}
func2 <- function(data, var){
  data %>% mutate(!!var/10)
}
```

In this MWE, `func(data,quo(V1))` works. `func2(data, quo(V1))` doesn't, it spits out `Error in var/10 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. That is, the very same strategy that allows `select()` to correctly evaluate "var" as "V1", does not allow `mutate()` to do the same.

Is there any reason, any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small fix is needed, specify the name of new column and add brackets.

`func2 <- function(data, var){
  data %>% mutate(V3 = (!!var)/10)
  }`